# Exclude a custom category from a list

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have some code that is generating a list of custom categories for a custom post type. This is the code:

```
    $html .=    '<ul class="item-direct-filters"><li class="first"><strong>view more:</strong></li>';
    $k = 0;
    foreach ( $terms as $term )
    {
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
        $k++;
        if ($term->name != "") $html .= '<li><a href="/work/' . $term->slug . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }

    $html .= '</ul>';
```

Any idea how I might go about tweaking this to exclude specific custom categories from the list? I'm thinking I need a line before the foreach to tell it to skip certain category ID's?

Many thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I am puzzled at how that could possibly work, even a little. You are setting your `$terms` variable *after* you start to try to loop over it. That makes no sense. A quick rewrite would make this a little better:

```
$html = '';
$html .=    '<ul class="item-direct-filters"><li class="first"><strong>view more:</strong></li>';
$taxonomy = 'category';
$k = 0;
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
foreach ( $terms as $term )
{
    $k++;
    if ($term->name != "") $html .= '<li><a href="/work/' . $term->slug . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}

$html .= '</ul>';

echo $html;
```

But that won't let you exclude a category. `get_the_terms()` is not natively capable of that, and you probably don't need to worry about a specialized query. [The results should be cached relatively well.](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8.1/src/wp-includes/category-template.php#L1090) Just exclude your term on the fly:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term )
{
    $k++;
    if ($term->name != "" && 1 !== $term->term_id) {
      $html .= '<li><a href="/work/' . $term->slug . '" class="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Notice the extra condition in the `if` statement.